# Sort Magento 2 Text Swatches Options

Tags: configurable-swatches

I want to make swatches in sorting in natural sorting order.
Like using below PHP function:
"`strnatcasecmp`"

I know it can be done through admin like drag and drop to size/color option. But I only want this done by programmatically as no matter what is the position set in the admin for these options.

Below is the file where these swatches are rendering:

```
vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/templates/product/view/renderer.phtml
```

Below is the screenshot is attached:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can override `/vendor/magento/module-swatches/Block/Product/Renderer/Configurable.php` file in your custom module for customisation in swatches.

You need to change in `public function getJsonSwatchConfig()` function for sort text swatches.

> /vendor/magento/module-swatches/Block/Product/Renderer/Configurable.php

```
public function getJsonSwatchConfig()
{
    $attributesData = $this->getSwatchAttributesData();
    $allOptionIds = $this->getConfigurableOptionsIds($attributesData);
    $swatchesData = $this->swatchHelper->getSwatchesByOptionsId($allOptionIds);

    $config = [];
    foreach ($attributesData as $attributeId => $attributeDataArray) {
        if (isset($attributeDataArray['options'])) {
            $config[$attributeId] = $this->addSwatchDataForAttribute(
                $attributeDataArray['options'],
                $swatchesData,
                $attributeDataArray
            );
        }
    }
    return $this->jsonEncoder->encode($config);
}
```

You just simply check for text swatches in `getJsonSwatchConfig()`:

```
if ($attributeDataArray['swatch_input_type'] == 'text') {
//Your custom code
}
```

I hope it will helpful for you.

Comment: can you pls show me how can I sort it as I have already tried this way, also the $config has valid data as I want, but on product page, its not working.